# HTML table to outlook via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, html-table, mimemultipart

I need to send an HTML table to outlook via python I tried this code but it isn't working it send an empty mail to me

```
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = "subject"
    msg['From'] = "from.com"
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(email_list)
    html = """table border="1" class="dataframe"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr style="text-align: right;"> 
      <th>DG Lead</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Krishnamurthy Ramamurthy</td> 
      <td>324</td> 
> 
    <tr> """
    msg.HTMLBody=html
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    s.sendmail("from.com", email_list, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete

Comment: Did you look at the email source? Is it really empty or does the html just not render because of the stray `>` and the missing closing tags?